# Splitting/saving h264 rtsp stream and de-payloading headers with ffmpeg without decoding/encoding in C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding, video-editing

I want to receive an h264-encoded stream over rtsp, read the metadata from the packet headers (to save into a database), split and save the video to disk without decoding/encoding the stream. The length of the split video segments can be fixed to, say, 5-10 minutes. I want to do this using the FFMpeg API in C++ (NOT command line!) with as little CPU overhead as possible because I need the headers. Can this be done using FFMpeg? Dare I ask if anyone can suggest tutorials? (I couldn't find anything other than command line examples)

Comment: You were able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. It has APIs to demux and decode. I don't think there is any documentation to explain this. You may go through ffmpeg applications - ffplay, ffserver.